# Multiplying Issue

Tags: c#, linq, multiplication

I'm trying to get the number of people who purchased a full price ticket to multiply with my full price (5.50). I'm try to put this number into my Label7 after when i press the calculate button. Can anyone help me do this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
namespace Burren_Bus_Tours
{
    public partial class BurrenBusToursForm : Form
    {
        public const double Full = 5.50;
        public const double Discount = 3.75;
        public BurrenBusToursForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label5.Text = TextBoxDriversName.Text;
            LabelDriver.Text = "Drivers Name:";
            LabelRiders.Text = "Total Riders:";
            LabelReceipts.Text = "Total Receipts:";
            LabelAverageReceipts.Text = "Average Receipts per Rider:";
            label6.Text = (double.Parse(TextBoxDiscountRiders.Text) + double.Parse(TextBoxFullFareRiders.Text)).ToString();
            GroupBoxData.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Hi I'm pretty new to coding and c#. I'm trying to get the number of people who purchased a full price ticket to multiply with my full price (5.50). I'm try to put this number into my Label7 after when i press the calculate button. Can anyone help me do this? Thanks!

Comment: Couple of things. (1) Take a look at the style guidelines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions to get a good idea on how you want variables, labels, etc to be capitalized. (2) I don't see a `label7` in you `ButtonCalculate_Click` event handler. What are you currently trying to populate the value? You will find people on this site are reluctant to provide you with an answer. Rather the goal is to help you find the flaw in what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, You need the number of people who have paid full price for ticket, Once you have that number you will the number with your constant price 5.50. So here is the basic logic of achieveing it. i am using console application to give you a hint.

Below is the class which will have Name, Id and whetere fullprice is paid or not

```
 public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public  string Fullname { get; set; }
    public  bool Fullprice { get; set; }
}
```

Now the main class which will call this class is below

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.Id = 1;
        ticket.Fullname = "Test1";
        ticket.Fullprice = true;

        Ticket ticket1 = new Ticket();
        ticket1.Id = 2;
        ticket1.Fullname = "Test2";
        ticket1.Fullprice = false;

        Ticket ticket2 = new Ticket();
        ticket2.Id = 3;
        ticket2.Fullname = "Test3";
        ticket2.Fullprice = true;

        Ticket ticket3 = new Ticket();
        ticket3.Id = 4;
        ticket3.Fullname = "Test4";
        ticket3.Fullprice = true;

        Ticket ticket4 = new Ticket();
        ticket4.Id = 5;
        ticket4.Fullname = "Test5";
        ticket4.Fullprice = false;

        Ticket ticket5 = new Ticket();
        ticket5.Id = 6;
        ticket5.Fullname = "Test6";
        ticket5.Fullprice = true;

        List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>();
        tickets.Add(ticket);
        tickets.Add(ticket1);
        tickets.Add(ticket2);
        tickets.Add(ticket3);
        tickets.Add(ticket4);
        tickets.Add(ticket5);
        var result = tickets.Where(t => t.Fullprice == true);
        int Count = 0;
        foreach (var noofpeople in result)
        {
            Count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Count*5.50);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

If you see this below line, it will get you the number of people who paid full price

```
   var result = tickets.Where(t => t.Fullprice == true);
```

Hope this helps.